# Error establishing a database connection - WP host changed password

Tags: php, mysql, database, wordpress

I changed my SQL password through my webbhost. After that I found out that I couldn't enter my website anymore. I'm 99% sure it has to do with the login credentials. So I was searching around on the internet and found the `define('WP_ALLOW_REPAIR', true);`-code but that didn't helped me. I also tried to replace the following in my `wp-config-sample.php`:

```
define('DB_NAME', 'database-name');
define('DB_USER', 'database-username');
define('DB_PASSWORD', 'database-password');`
```

Another strange thing I found out is there is 2 folders. One `wp-config.php` and another one where all the credentialinfo is called `wp-config-sample.php`. Maybe it doesn't matter. Is there anyone who had a similar problem and fixed it or someone who could help me?

Comment: The obvious question here is did you update your wp-config.php file after changing the password with your webhost?

Answer (score 2):

The active config file is wp-config.php.
The file wp-config-sample.php is only a sample file and is there in order to help set up configuration manually.

With that said, if the accurate and current credentials are not updated on the wp-config.php file, it will be impossible to establish DB connection.